# Symfony catch PHP errors in CLI command

Tags: php, symfony, error-handling, symfony-3.2

I have a Symfony 3.2 app. I created a command to run some background task. I have to know when the command finished even if it resulted in an exception or fatal error.

My first idea was to surround my code with `try/catch` block. I am able to catch exceptions generated in my code or in PHP libraries as `PDO` but not core fatal errors. Then I tried to receive the error so I pushed a handler to the app logger. Again I intercept exceptions but not fatal errors. Here is how I add the handler to the logger:

```
$logger = $this->getContainer()->get('logger');
$handler = $this->getContainer()->get('app.bg_command_log_handler');
$logger->pushHandler(self::$handler);
```

Here is the handler:

```
use Monolog\Handler\AbstractProcessingHandler;

class BgCommandLogHandler extends AbstractProcessingHandler
{
    protected function write(array $record)
    {
        var_dump($record);
    }
}
```

Symfony version is 3.2 and PHP is 5.6.

Comment: @yivi Hi,sorry,I was away for couple of days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set a custom error handler with `set_error_handler()`, as described [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php).

Use your error handler to `throw()` exceptions when errors are raised. This way, anything that could raise a fatal error would throw an exception of your choice instead, and you'd be able to catch it.

Of course, this would affect your whole application, not only this specific command. But I think it's a good thing.

As an aside, you should really try to upgrade your PHP runtime, if possible. 5.6 has not been supported for a long while.

Comment: I can imagine this will work BUT doesn't Symfony already do this? Doesn't it convert PHP errors to exceptions?

Comment: It does I recent versions. You are using an ancient stack, so I’m not sure. But if you say you are not catching the exceptions, I’d say not all of the are being converted. Why not try my suggestion and see if it works?

Comment: "ancient"? :) isn't it a bit exaggerated :) but yes, I set a custom `set_error_handler` and as expected, everything is reported to me.

Comment: Well, Sf 3.2 has been released 3 years ago, and it's almost two since its last security patch. The situation with PHP 5.6 is similar. I feel your pain, dealing with a hard to upgrade stack is not nice.